# Date function issue with strptime $mon not working in R

Tags: r, time

Can anyone explain this....

```
>strptime("19300307", "%Y%m%d")
   "1930-03-07"
>unlist(strptime("19300307", "%Y%m%d"))
   sec   min  hour  mday   mon  year  wday  yday isdst 
    0     0     0     7     2    30     5    65     0
```

All of a sudden my strptime is confusing me...
Why is mon = 2 rather than 3?

Comment: Try with January. Maybe it starts at 0?

Comment: @joran You are correct sir! (the only 0 indexed thing in R?)

Comment: @Justin I can't think of any other examples, but I'm sure there are a few out there.

Comment: It's actually POSIX behaviour; same thing in C.

Comment: Also days, hour, min, sec, yday start at 0. Logical FALSE is 0 which makes it unsuitable for indexing vectors unless you add 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following my comment, if you read `?DateTimeClasses`, you'll see that for POSIXlt we have:

> 0–11: months after the first of the year.